# Compilation error when instantiating object

Tags: java, constructor, access-modifiers

I just want to make an object. But I don't know why this error comes up. I thought everything was right but constructor error pop up. And it said required String,String,int no argument. Why is that?

```
error: constructor Account in class Account cannot iven types required: String,String,int found: no arguments reason: actual and formal argument
```

My code

```
class Account{
    private String accName;
    private String accID;
    private int balance;
    private Account(){
        accName = "No name found";
        accID = "No id found";
    }
    private Account(String name, String id, int bal){
        accName = name;
        accID = id;
        balance = bal;
    }
    private void Withdrow(int amount){
        if(balance > amount)
        {
        balance = balance - amount;
        System.out.println("Balance :"+balance);
        }
        else
            System.out.println("Not Enough money");
    }
    private void deposit(int amount){
        if(amount>0)
        {
        balance = balance + amount;
        System.out.println("Balance :"+balance);
        }
        else
            System.out.println("Error Deposit");
    }
    private void showInfo(){
        System.out.println("Name :"+ accName);
        System.out.println("ID :"+ accID);
        System.out.println("Balance :"+ balance);
    }
}

class Main{

    public static void main(String args[]){

        Account ac = new Account();

    }
}
```

Comment: Parameterless contructor is private. EIther make it public or use parameters when you create object using parametrized one.

Answer (score 0):

Make your constructor public and initialize `balance` property

```
public Account(){
    accName = "No name found";
    accID = "No id found";
    balance = 0;
}
```

Comment: @lealceldeiro relying on such default values is generally considered bad programming style.

Comment: FYI: All integer fields are zero if not initialized, so putting `balance = 0` is superfluous